# Laravel Javascript: Edit Page radio button function that appends input field when i click other option

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I have a radio button with other option that appends input field when click

here is my code

**View:**

```
             <div class="input-field col s4 floor_level">
                <p>
                  <label>Floor Level<h7 class="red-text">*</h7></label><br>
                  <label>
                    <input id="ground" class="with-gap" name="floor_level" type="radio" value="Ground" {{ $client->eventDetail->floor_level == 'Ground' ? 'checked' : ''}}/>
                    <span>Ground</span>
                  </label>
                </p>
                <p>
                  <label>
                    <input id="rooftop" class="with-gap" name="floor_level" type="radio" value="Rooftop" {{ $client->eventDetail->floor_level == 'Rooftop' ? 'checked' : ''}}/>
                    <span>Rooftop</span>
                  </label>
                </p>
                <p>
                  <label>
                    <input id="option" class="with-gap" name="floor_level" type="radio" value="other" {{ old('floor_level',$new_floor_level) == 'other' ? 'checked' : '' }}/>
                    <span id="otherlabel">Other</span>
                  </label>
                </p>
            </div>
```

**Script:**

```
<script>
$(function () {
  var $select2 = $('#option');

  $select2.on('change', function (e) {

      if($(this).val()==="other"){
        $('#option').one('click', function() {
        $('.floor_level').append('<div class="added_input"><input id="floor_level_input" type="text" name="floor_level" value="{{ old('floor_level',$client->eventDetail->floor_level) }}" placeholder="Specify.." class="validate"><label for="floor_level_input">Make your own selection!</label></div>');
        $('#option').hide();
        $('#otherlabel').hide();

    });
  }

  }).change();


   $('#rooftop').change(function () {
        if($(this).val()!=="other"){
        $('.added_input').remove();
        $('#option').show();
        $('#otherlabel').show();
        }
    });

   $('#ground').change(function () {
        if($(this).val()!=="other"){
        $('.added_input').remove();
        $('#option').show();
        $('#otherlabel').show();
        }
    });

  });
</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
$client = Client::findOrFail($id);

if ($client->eventDetail->floor_level !== "Ground" AND $client->eventDetail->floor_level != "Rooftop")
        {
            $new_floor_level = "other";
        }
        else
        {
            $new_floor_level = " ";
        }

return view('admin.clients.edit', compact('client', 'new_floor_level'));
```

In my **create page** this code is working, when i click the the **"Other"** radio button there will be an input field and when i click the Ground or Rooftop the input field will be removed.

The question is how can i show the appended input field with the value from database if the radio button is **Other** by default in my **update page**, and still works with click event that removes the input field when i click Ground or Rooftop and show it again when i click Other.

[image: This photo for reference]

[image]

Comment: in create page you must have Storing input field value in the database? then you just need to populate in the edit mode right?

Comment: I suggest hiding the input instead of removing it

Comment: @this.girish yes, the thing is when i click the edit i don't get the appended input field, but i get to check the Others. To append the input field i need to click the Other one more time.

Comment: @anas bakro I tried to hide the input field but when i submit then the value sending to the controller doesn't change

Comment: Can't you check if input is null or empty on page load and enable the radio button accordingly, fire change event then?

Comment: with append input field i can create a new instance of input field and delete it if i no longer need it, but this case i have a default value which is not equal to Ground and Rooftop so i get to check the Other but what i want is not to check the Other, what i want is to show input field with the value for example "1st" like in the photo, and if i want to change it to clicking the Ground radio for example then the input field will be remove.

Comment: @this.girish i don't think checking if it's null will help because there is always a value if i edit either Ground or Rooftop or Other but i will try.